# Google groups in Android replying only to sender

Tags: google-groups

When I receive a google groups email on my android and hit reply the email address for the reply is only to the sender and not the group. How do I change that?

Answer (score 1):

According to this post, it looks like you can't change this:
http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Apps/thread?tid=2b38333c484cca1e&hl=en